# why [1] is not the output for range(1,5,-1) function in python?

Tags: python

why [1] is not the output for range(1,5,-1) function in python?

The start and stop will produce 1,2,3,4 and the step will give 1,0,-1 ... and so on, so the element '1' is common among them but why still 1 is not included in this?

Comment: Since step is negative, the range only includes numbers `<= 1` and `> 5`. Which is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range(a, b, c)` function is defined as the value will go from `a` to `b` with interval of `c` in each step.
It will cover the values the following way:
`[a, a+c, a+2c, ..., a+nc]` where `a+nc` is the maximum value satisfying `a+nc < b` and `n` is an integer.

So, when you do `range(1, 5, -1)`, it tries to go from `1` to `5` by adding `-1`, but as 5 is already greater than 1, it will stop.
If you want to iterate from 5 to 1, you can do it the following way:

```
range(5, 0, -1)
```

then the value goes in the following way: `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

Answer (score 2):

Range function takes 3 arguments (Start, Stop, Step).
If you are providing a negative step, the **Stop** value need to be less than **Start** value.